# Find filenames in folder automatically

Tags: c#, file, sorting, filter

I have a folder with filenames like :

```
v5.9.1.55
v5.9.2.34 
v5.9.2.65 
v5.9.5.12
```

I have a dropbox where i can select a version like: 5.9.1, 5.9.2, 5.9.3, 5.9.4

So when i have lets say, 5.9.1 selected it searches the folder for files containing 5.9.1. When i have several i sort them to get the file with the highes subversion. Lets say i have 5.9.1.12 and 5.9.1.44 i would get 5.9.1.44.

But my boss said that when there is no file for this version i should use the file closest below that version. So from the examples on top, if i have 5.9.3 selected in the dropbox, i wouldnt be able to find a file containing 5.9.3 because there isnt one. It is now expected that the next file below, in this case 5.9.2.34 is targetet.

But how should i be able to target a file i cant search for because i dont know IF the file i want isnt here and so i have to search for one below and WHAT the closest file version would be. This would all have to happen programmically but I'm out of ideas right now.

I hope someone of you can help me tackle this and maybe provide an idea where i can work myself to succeed in this.

This would be my code right now where i can find the right file IF there is one present that fits the selected version:

```
string ComboboxText = ComboBoxVersion.Text;
if (ComboboxText != "")
{
    string[] TempContainingDirectorys = new string[54];
    int containingdirectorysCount = 0;
    string[] directoryEntriesLibVersions = Directory.GetDirectories(SourcepathString + @"\Programm\xxx");
    for (int a = 0; a < directoryEntriesLibVersions.Length; a++)
    {
        if (directoryEntriesLibVersions[a].Contains(ComboBoxVersion.Text))
        {
            TempContainingDirectorys[containingdirectorysCount] = directoryEntriesLibVersions[a];
            containingdirectorysCount++;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    IComparer revComparer = new ReverseComparer();
    Array.Sort(TempContainingDirectorys, revComparer);
    string newtestClient = TempContainingDirectorys[0];
}
```

**UPDATE FIX:
I went with the idea to seperate it into major, minor, bugfix versions. And then if nothing was found, decreased them one by one.
This is the working code:**

```
int FOUND = 0;
TempContainingDirectorys = new string[54];
containingdirectorysCount = 0;
string VersionPunkte = ComboBoxVersion.Text.Replace('_', '.');
while(FOUND == 0){

    directoryEntriesLibVersions = Directory.GetDirectories(SourcepathString + @"\Programm\xxx");
    for (int a = 0; a < directoryEntriesLibVersions.Length; a++)
    {
        if (directoryEntriesLibVersions[a].Contains(VersionPunkte))
        {
            TempContainingDirectorys[containingdirectorysCount] = directoryEntriesLibVersions[a];
            containingdirectorysCount++;
            FOUND = 1;
        }
    }
    if (containingdirectorysCount == 0)
    {
        char delimiter = '.';
        string[] substringsVersion = VersionPunkte.Split(delimiter);
        int found = 0;
        int Majorversion = Int32.Parse(substringsVersion[0]);
        int Minorversion = Int32.Parse(substringsVersion[1]);
        int Bugfixversion = Int32.Parse(substringsVersion[2]);

        if (Bugfixversion > 0)
        {
            Bugfixversion = Bugfixversion-1;
        }
        else
        {
        Minorversion = Minorversion-1;
        Bugfixversion = 9;
        }
        VersionPunkte = Majorversion.ToString() + "." + Minorversion.ToString() + "." + Bugfixversion.ToString();
    }
    Array.Sort(TempContainingDirectorys, revComparer);
}

string newtestPEnv = TempContainingDirectorys[0];
```

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Start with [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively you could split the "5.9.3" on '.' and get different numeric values as e.g. majorVersion = 5, minorVersion = 9, buggFixVersion = 3

And then start decreasing them in descending order of importance. For each version you search for a matching file, if one is found then stop and return it-

Do this until you reach version 0.0.0, if you haven't found anything by then there is not much to do!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea, i will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion on how to do it with `Version`:

First create a `Dictionary` with all files with the associated version (your looking for Directories in your example).
Then search for the exact number, if not found looking for the nearest version:

```
//Your combobox string
Version loSelectedVersion = new Version("5.9.4");

Dictionary<Version, string> loVersionFiles = new Dictionary<Version, string>();
foreach (var lsFilename in Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Temp\Version"))
{
    var loMatch = Regex.Match(lsFilename, @"(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)");
    if (loMatch.Success)
        loVersionFiles.Add(new Version(loMatch.Value), lsFilename);
}

//Excact match with your selectedVersion
var loEntry = loVersionFiles
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault(item => string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", item.Key.Major, item.Key.Minor, item.Key.Build) == loSelectedVersion.ToString());

if (loEntry.Key != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(loEntry.Value);
}
else
{
    //Version Not Found -> look for the nearest
    loEntry = loVersionFiles
        .OrderByDescending(item => item.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key < loSelectedVersion);
    if (loEntry.Key != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(loEntry.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I generate a class to sort versions using IComparable.  I also added a Floor method to get version just below the one needed.  See if this works.  I added some sample test data while I debugged the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           string[] inputs = { "v5.9.1.55", "v5.9.2.34", "v5.9.2.65",  "v5.9.5.12"};
            //demonstrates order by works
           string[] orderResults = inputs.OrderBy(x => new VersionSort(x)).ToArray();


            //sample test data to check class
           string[] testinputs = { "v4.9", "v5", "v5.9.1.2", "v5.9.2.65", "v5.10" };

            VersionSort testVersion = new VersionSort();
           foreach (string test in testinputs)
           {
               string floor = testVersion.Floor(test, inputs);

               Console.WriteLine("Version : '{0}', Floor : '{1}'", test, floor);
           }
           Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
    public class VersionSort : IComparable 
    {
        int[] versionNumbers = null;

        public VersionSort() { }
        public VersionSort(string str)
        {
            //skip the first character v
            versionNumbers = str.Substring(1).Split(new char[] { '.' }).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
        }

        public int CompareTo(object other)
        {
            VersionSort version = (VersionSort)other;

            int minlength = versionNumbers.Length < version.versionNumbers.Length ? versionNumbers.Length : version.versionNumbers.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < minlength; i++)
            {
                if (versionNumbers[i] == version.versionNumbers[i]) continue;
                return versionNumbers[i].CompareTo(version.versionNumbers[i]);
            }
            return versionNumbers.Length.CompareTo(version.versionNumbers.Length);
        }
        public string Floor(string compareVersionStr, string[] inputArray)
        {
            VersionSort compareversion = new VersionSort(compareVersionStr);
            VersionSort[] sortedVersions = inputArray.Select( x => new VersionSort(x)).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

            if(compareversion.CompareTo(sortedVersions[0]) == -1) return string.Empty;


            int index = 0;
            for (; index < sortedVersions.Length; index++ )
            {
                int comparResults = compareversion.CompareTo(sortedVersions[index]);
                if (comparResults == 0) return inputArray[index];
                if (comparResults < 0) return inputArray[index - 1];
            }

            return inputArray.LastOrDefault();
        }
    }


}
```